# Stop one PrimaryKeyID (Int) used in place of another in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, integer, primary-key, standards

Our database uses auto incrementing integers to store Primary Key fields. These fields are accessed using C#. Recently we've had issues with developers using the wrong primary key fields without thoroughly testing the results. e.g.

```
int systemUserID = 1234;
string companyName = company.getCompanyNameFromCompanyID(systemUserID);
```

As you can expect this results in incorrect information being returned. What I am looking for is a solution to reduce the ability for developers to input incorrect IDs when using primary key fields.

Unit Testing is an option but would only work if the data going in is wrong.
Changing the primary key fields to GUIDs is not an option due to the database size and the errors that would be introduced.

Any way that anyone has seen this before and stopped/limited it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem is that you have developers passing incorrect Id values when retrieving data?
I don't see how you can prevent this in your C# code. You should be performing code reviews which would normally catch errors like this. Plus, I just don't see how something like this can be a major issue in your code unless most of your developers are very inexperienced and not paying attention. Even more reason to do code reviews.

Comment: Code reviews are already done for code that is considered high risk but now it is currently looking like the only way is to code review everything submitting. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't any other formal standards that might have been realised before putting further code reviews in place.

Comment: I don't think there is any 'formal standard' to deal with this except to pay attention to what you're doing. I've never heard of something like this being an issue. As a side note, make sure to accept whatever answer you find helpful, so you're more like to get people to help you in the future. I tell you this because you appear to be new here.

Comment: Thanks Randy. I was waiting to see if there was any more answers to come forward but I think you're right in that it's just a matter of paying attention and ramping up code reviews.

Comment: Are the developers on your team fairly inexperienced?

Comment: Its fairly common that new developers brought in are juniors in need of further training.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are asking...

So, you have developers that are coding your software and they make mistakes like the example you have above?  (Looking for a company and sending a userID instead of a companyID to the context).

This a careless mistake.  The only way to fix a careless mistake is to find out why it was done.  Are your developers experienced enough?  Are they motivated?  Are they overworked?

This is more of a personnel issue than a technical one, I think.